# How long is the MapboxMap instance valid?

Tags: android, mapbox

In order to obtain a `MapboxMap` instance you call [`getMapAsync()`](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/5.0.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapView.html#getMapAsync-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback-) and get it returned in `onMapReady()`. My question is: for how long is this `MapboxMap` instance valid? Can I store a reference to it and use it again later, and when do I need to invalidate it?

To me it seems that the `MapboxMap` instance becomes invalid after [`onDestroy()`](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/5.0.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapView.html#onDestroy--) has been called on the `MapView`, but I can't see it properly documented anywhere.

As a related question, I'm also wondering how long it's safe to keep a reference to a `Marker` (in order to update it). It also seems to become invalid after `onDestroy()` has been called.

Is there a best practices, or recommended way to deal with this? Should one never store a reference to a `MapboxMap` in an `Activity` or `Fragment`, or is there a listener one should register for?

Comment: The relation between Mapview and MapboxMap is one-to-one. You are not able to relink an exisiting MapboxMap to a second Mapview. A MapboxMap is valid as long as the Mapview is. Same goes for Marker. Feel free to store a reference of these objects in Activity/Fragment as these will live as long as the mapview/mapboxmap.

Comment: @Tobrun Thanks. I already went ahead and did this and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question for others who might wonder:

`Marker` and `MapboxMap` instances are valid as long as their `MapView` is valid. So it's ***safe to keep a reference to them until the `MapView` is destroyed***. Thanks @Tobrun for clarifying this in the comment above.